# Jackrabbit: best way to make my own webapp + WebDAV

Tags: webdav, jcr, jackrabbit

I need to code a JCR webapp with webdav. I'm a little confused, because I think there might be many approaches - but I don't know beforehand which will work, and which will be better / less work than the others.

And one thing that is important is that I need to provide my own extended AccessManager (which must also be used by the webdav component): Only the lockOwner (and admins/system) is allowed to unlock a node, no matter if in the same session or later.

- use jackrabbit-webapp code as a base (merge new versions of the jackrabbit-webapp into it)
- start from scratch and use jackrabbit-webdav.jar as a lib and use some code from jackrabbit-webapp for providing webdav servlets
- use jackrabbit-webapp as a server component (Deployment Model 1, but can I plant my AccessManager on it then?)

Hope to get some insights :)
Karsten

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Sling](http://sling.apache.org) is a good option for JCR-based web applications, although its out-of-the box launchpad distribution has many features, it's very modular so you could use just what you need and end up with a small runnable jar (or Karaf feature) for your project. Compared to starting from scratch, Sling provides many useful features like a configuration and monitoring console, standard servlets and pluggability of most everything.